# insert the content between matching pattern in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to insert the content between the matching pattern in shell please help on this

For example :

file called input.txt :

```
var a = [ ]
```

file called output.txt :

```
1152
1185
1185
```

I want to insert the values from output.txt file to the file input.txt.
it should be like var a = [1152 1185 1185]

Comment: Please take care with your formatting and explain to us more clearly what you're trying to do.

Comment: can u get my point now???

Comment: No, you haven't made any significant changes to your question to make it any more clear. Use code blocks to show us your current input(s) and the desired output.

Comment: input.txt "var a = [  ]"

output.txt "1152"
i want to insert the value from output.txt to input.txt after finding a matching pattern. i tried by ***sed  "/ \  [  /r output.txt" input.txt*** 
obtained output: var a = [  ] 1152
expected output : var a = [ 1152 ]

Comment: Do you have several lines in your files or just one like in the example ?

Comment: i have multiple numeric values in file

Comment: ...and what do you want to do with the rest of them? Please [edit] your question to provide us with a complete example, taking care to preserve the formatting that @Lordofdark has added.

Comment: Does `input.txt` contain any more lines? does it contain more lines with `[]`?

Comment: Try the following `sed "s/\[/[ $(xargs < output.txt)/" input.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed "s/\[/[ $(xargs < output.txt)/" input.txt
```

`xargs < filename` dumps all file lines in just one, i.e., replaces EOL characters for SPACE characters.

`$(xargs < filename)` expands to the contents of the `filename` in just one line. Hence the use of double quotes, not single ones.

Comment: It worked ... Thanks much Jdamian

Comment: I need to add comma between those numbers .. is it possible to done through suggested command  ("sed "s/\[/[ $(xargs < output.txt)/" input.txt")


Desired output:

var a = [123 , 456 , 789]